# How to insert the same random number for another column's value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-statement

Within my table `'SERVICE_TICKET'` are two columns, namely `'Defect_Description'` and `'Defect_Description_Code'`.
I'd like to populate the second column with random numbers between 1000000 and 9999999 (7-digit-number). However, the random number should be the same for equal values within the first column. So for example if the 'Defect_Description'`= 'microphone for hands-free device',`the'Defect_Description_Code'should always equal the same arbitrary number, e.g.'8374917'`.

I came up with the following expression, but this creates a diffirent number for each `'Defect_Description'`. What do I need to change in order to get the same number for each of these?

```
UPDATE dbo.SERVICE_TICKET
SET Defect_Description_Code = 
    CASE Defect_Description
        WHEN 'microphone for hands-free device' THEN (ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 1111111 + 9999999)
        ELSE '-'
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to avoid `newid()` in this case.  I would recommend simply using `Defect_Desription` itself.

The following query also fixes the logic to get the 7 digit number:

```
UPDATE dbo.SERVICE_TICKET
    SET Defect_Description_Code = ABS(CHECKSUM(Defect_Description)) % 9000000 + 1000000;
```